# Question on finding the electric field?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, potential

> Find the electric field strength vector at the centre of a ball of radius $R$ with volume charge density $p=\vec{a}\cdot \vec{r}$, where $a$ is a constant vector, and $r$ is a radius vector drawn from the ball's centre.

I approached it as follows by considering a disc element.But the answer is given as aR<sup>2</sup>/6∈. I checked that there is no calculation error.But I don't know what am I doing wrong?
[image]

Comment: What is the direction of the electric field vector at the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your calculation of the surface density. The $Rd\theta$ is not perpendicular to the plane of the disk, but makes an angle $\theta$ with it. Thus, an additional factor of $\sin\theta$ appears:
$$
d\sigma = aR^2\cos\theta\sin\theta\,d\theta = -aR^2\cos\theta\,d\cos\theta
$$
After that the integral becomes
$$
E=-2\frac{aR^2}{2\epsilon}\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta(1-\cos\theta)\,d\cos\theta=\frac{aR^2}{\epsilon}\int_0^1x(1-x)dx
$$
Thus
$$
E = -\frac{aR^2}{\epsilon}\left[\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3\right]_0^1dx = -\frac{aR^2}{6\epsilon}
$$
The minus sign is because the positively charged hemisphere is to the right, while the negatively charged hemisphere is to the left, so the electrical field is looking to the left.